# Return a table variable from CLR stored procedure call

Tags: c#, clr, sql-server-2012, sqlclr, clrstoredprocedure

I have an existing CLR that uses XST to shred and validate XML passed in.  I want to capture the data points (don't care about the XML itself) into a table that can be directly inserted into a database table.  So I'd call my CLR stored proc and it would return 4 columns with hundreds or rows and I could simply do an

```
insert into EXISTINGtable 
select * from TableReturnedFromCLRspCAll
```

It doesn't have to be an SP it could be a UDF ... my real question is how do I get CLR to return a table.  I need to be able to pass in the table definition as well.  So for the table that is being returned by the CLR ... I would like to have the 4 column names and types be part of the call to the CLR as variables.

If someone can help me with this I would be most grateful and very impressed because I've asked around to some very seasoned guys and they all throw up their hands when I get to the CLR having a dynamic table AND/OR CLR returning a table at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx

> Returning Tabular Results
>
> To send the results of a query directly to the client, use one of the
>   overloads of the Execute method on the SqlPipe object. This is the
>   most efficient way to return results to the client, since the data is
>   transferred to the network buffers without being copied into managed
>   memory.

I haven't tried it from a stored procedure, but I have returned a table from a CLR UDF using the following example.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131103.aspx